# How to delete 3 billion rows from 2 related tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 5 billion rows (table1) another table with 3 billion rows in table 2. These 2 tables are related. I have to delete 3 billion rows from table 1 and its related rows from table 2. Table1 is child of table 2. I tried using the for all method from plsql it didn't help much. Then I thought of using oracle partition strategy. Since I am not a DBA I would like to know if partioning of a existing table is possible on primary key column for a selected number of id's? My primary key is 64 bit auto generated number.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle 11g

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to partition the objects online(it can be done using dbms_redefinition). And not necessary(with the details you gave).

Best ideea would be to recreate the objects without the undesired rows.

For example some simple code would be like:

```
create table undesired_data as (select undesired rows from table1);
Create table1_new as (select * from table1 where key not in (select key from undesired_data));
Create table2_new as (select * from table2 where key not in (select key from undesired_data));
rename table1 to table1_old;
rename table2 to table2_old;
rename table1_new to table1;
rename table2_new to table2;
recreate constraints;
check if everything is ok;
drop table1_old and table2_old;
```

This can be done offlining consumers, but would be very small downtime for them if scripts are ok(you should test them in a test environment).

Comment: This would also be an opportunity to move to a partitioned table as well, of course, for next time.

Comment: @DavidAldridge  Thanks for the quick reply. Another approach I thought of was take the table offline create a new partition with the required rows.Then drop the partition with unwanted rows. I can identify the required  rows. But I am not sure if partitioning can be done on the identified rows based on primary key. Do you have any examples for partioning existing table based on primary key? Also I would like to know if the CTAS approach over partioning will save time?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very dubious.
If it is real use-case then you don't delete you create another table, well defined, including partitioned and you fill it using `insert /*+ append */ into MyNewTable select ...`.
The most common practice is to define partitions on dates (record create date, event date etc.).
Again, if this is a real use-case I strongly recommend that you will reach for real help, not seek for advice on the internet and not doing it yourself.

Comment: Note, partitioning requires you purchase a license for that option as well as Enterprise edition.

Comment: @BLaZuRE, If he is just playing around so nothing really matters, but if it is a business than he should act like a business and keep up with the industry standards by purchasing a license or move to free solution that gives him similar capabilities or else he will find himself with huge dead tables and no business.